# Make post slug have priority over category slug

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a wordpress site where the category base is stripped from the url.

Now, when a category has a certain slug that's similar to a post slug, the category is shown.

I would like to show the post instead. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the slugs that are causing the problem and explain the mechanism you used to strip the category from the URL?

Comment: example url: http://www.example.com/wordpress/cars/
where "cars" is both slug for a post and for a category.

The mechanism I've used for stripping the category base is the same that is used in the WP No Category Base plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a clean way to do what you're asking. What you want is for WordPress to check to see if, for a given URL, there is a post with that slug, and if not, try to find a category with that slug. With the exception of pages, WordPress doesn't check to see if an opject (post, term) exists before "committing" to a matching rewrite rule. Therefore, when you have conflicting rewrite rules, the second one will never be read.

The best answer is to find a different rewrite structure for your posts or categories. Prefixes are ideal, like `/blog/%postname%/`, `/articles/%postname%/` for posts, or `/category/%category%/`, `/topic/%category%/` for categories.

That said, it's not impossible to do what you're asking, it's just not optimal. What you need to do is intercept the `request` and check to see if the post exists. If not, alter the query vars. Note that this adds to every post's page load, so weigh the costs against the benefits. Also remember that if a post and category share the same name, there's no accessing the category. Without further ado,

```
function wpse_75604_check_rewrite_conflicts( $qv ) {
    if ( isset( $qv['name'] ) ) {
        if ( ! get_page_by_path( $qv['name'], OBJECT, 'post' ) ) {
            $qv['category_name'] = $qv['name'];
            unset( $qv['name'] );
        }
    }
    return $qv;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'wpse_75604_check_rewrite_conflicts' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/22438/how-to-make-pages-slug-have-priority-over-any-other-taxonomies-like-custom-post) by replacing `page_rewrite_rules` filter with `post_rewrite_rules`, making post rewrite rules to have the top most priority.

Comment: At first it seemed to work. Post are shown when they should. But now all categories disappeared, I can't get them to show up. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @bertkat You mean, you have 404/not found error on categories? Did you try flushing the rewrite rules?

Comment: Yes Parham, I have 404 on all categories. Also tried flushing rewrite rules and also tried without stripping category base.