# How to create a permalink for custom taxonomies and custom post types like base-name/parent-tax/child-tax/custom-post-type-name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks

I found [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39500/how-to-create-a-permalink-structure-with-custom-taxonomies-and-custom-post-types) link too much helpful.
This is what I code so far and got it working for all scenarios except two scenarios.

```
register_post_type( 'article',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => 'Article',
            'singular_name' => 'Article',
            'add_new' => 'Add Article',
            'add_new_item' => 'Add New Article',
            'edit' => 'Edit',
            'edit_item' => 'Edit Article',
            'new_item' => 'New Article',
            'view' => 'View',
            'view_item' => 'View Article',
            'search_items' => 'Search Article',
            'not_found' => 'No Article',
            'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Post found in Article',
            'parent' => 'Parent Article'
        ),

        'public' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 15,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'thumbnail' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
        'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/img/icon_article.png',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'articles/%article_category%',
            'with_front' => true
        ),
        'has_archive' => 'articles',
        'register_meta_box_cb' => 'add_article_metaboxes'
    )
);



register_taxonomy('article_category','article',array(
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'articles', 'hierarchical' => true),
  ));

add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'mmp_rewrite_rules');
function mmp_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $newRules  = array();
    $newRules['articles/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?article=$matches[3]'; 
    $newRules['articles/(.+)/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?article=$matches[2]';
    $newRules['articles/(.+)/?$'] = 'index.php?article_category=$matches[1]'; 

    return array_merge($newRules, $rules);
}

function filter_post_type_link($link, $post)
{
    if ($post->post_type != 'article')
        return $link;

    if ($cats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'article_category'))
    {
        $link = str_replace('%article_category%', get_taxonomy_parents(array_pop($cats)->term_id, 'article_category', false, '/', true), $link); // see custom function defined below
    }
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);

// my own function to do what get_category_parents does for other taxonomies
function get_taxonomy_parents($id, $taxonomy, $link = false, $separator = '/', $nicename = false, $visited = array()) {    
    $chain = '';   
    $parent = &get_term($id, $taxonomy);

    if (is_wp_error($parent)) {
        return $parent;
    }

    if ($nicename)    
        $name = $parent -> slug;        
    else    
        $name = $parent -> name;

    if ($parent -> parent && ($parent -> parent != $parent -> term_id) && !in_array($parent -> parent, $visited)) {    
        $visited[] = $parent -> parent;    
        $chain .= get_taxonomy_parents($parent -> parent, $taxonomy, $link, $separator, $nicename, $visited);

    }

    if ($link) {
        // nothing, can't get this working :(
    } else {   
        $chain .= $name . $separator;    
    }
    return $chain;    
}
```

But this solution not working in two scenarios.

1st Scenario: On Child Taxonomy direct link
e.g: sitename.com/articles/parenttax/childtax/

2nd Scenario: On Pagination of Custom Post page
e.g: sitename.com/articles/parenttax/childtax/postname/page/2

Do I have to create separate function for them or just need to add new rules for it?

Answer (score 0):

When you create permalink structures like `/article/%category%/%postname%/`, it becomes very complicated when `%category%` is hierarchical. The problem WordPress runs into is knowing if after the second slash, the next part of the URL is a category or a post. For instance, in the url `/article/parent/child/`, is "child" a subcategory of "parent", or is it a post named "child"? In your case, it's even worse because your articles are also hierarchical.

Your best bet is to add a predictable or static separator between the two. Here are some examples:

```
/%article_category%/articles/%article%/
/articles/%article_category%/article/%article%/
/articles/%article_category%/%year%/%article%/
```

If you insist on maintaining the structure you propose, it's not impossible, but it would require some custom programming far beyond the scope of a Q & A site like this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt response. Okay Matthew I got your point. But still one question is coming in mind that can we create two separate functions or rules. One rule/function if child category is last url segment and second rule/function if post name is last url segment.

Apologies in advance, if question does not make sense.

Comment: Yes, you could. See [my answer here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75604/make-post-slug-have-priority-over-category-slug/100747#100747) on intercepting the request object and altering it. It would still require a good deal of custom programming outside the scope of this site. Furthermore, that's going to create a great deal of issues with feeds, pagination, trackbacks, etc. If I were you, I'd definitely go with the separator in the URL.

Comment: Okay Matthew I agreed with you and applied the separator and it worked very well for me. 
But It created another issue, actually I have one another taxonomy in my site which is 'gallery_category'. And all of its tax, child tax and custom post pages giving 404 error.
In fact I have not applied any url rewriting on it.

Comment: And neither defined rewrite in register_taxonomy and register_posttype. Still it is not working, I don't know why. Please help me in thi.

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, so you should open a separate question.

Comment: Okay created it. Please come on this link http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101022/change-in-custom-taxonomy-permalink-cause-404-error-for-another-custom-taxonomy