# Customizing URL slugs of Custom Post Type and Taxonomy make posts/pages 404

Tags: posts, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, customization

This problem has been for bugging me for days and I feel that I am close!

Creating a review website, I have custom post type called `review`, organized in a custom hierarchical taxonomy `niche`. Put simply, my end goal is for my URLs to look like this:

`mysite.com/coffee-maker/`: shows niche page template

`mysite.com/coffee-maker/keurig-k425`: shows individual `review`

I have tried the solution offered here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5313/1685, which led to two problems:

- CPTs worked fine but all my pages and posts return 404 errors.
  Looking at the Rewrite Analyser, I realized they are routed to the
  "niche:" rule. I realize there might be a conflict but don't know
  where to go from here!
- Intra-page taxonomy links such as those    generated using
  `get_category_link()` still append the `/niche/`    prefix to URL,
  which make them 404 too.

I feel I am close to finding what I need but saddened by the fact that this seems beyond me. Thanks a lot!

---

My chunks of code:

```
function cptui_register_my_cpts_review() {

    /**
     * Post Type: Reviews.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Reviews", "" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Review", "" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Mes Reviews", "" ),
        "all_items" => __( "Toutes les Reviews", "" ),
        "add_new" => __( "Ajouter une Review", "" ),
        "add_new_item" => __( "Ajouter une Review", "" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Modifier la Review", "" ),
        "new_item" => __( "Nouvelle Review", "" ),
        "view_item" => __( "Voir la Review", "" ),
        "view_items" => __( "Voir les Reviews", "" ),
        "search_items" => __( "Rechercher une Review", "" ),
        "not_found" => __( "Pas de Review Trouvée", "" ),
        "not_found_in_trash" => __( "Pas de Review Trouvée dans Corbeille", "" ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( "Review Parente", "" ),
        "insert_into_item" => __( "Insérer dans la Review", "" ),
        "uploaded_to_this_item" => __( "Insérer dans la Review", "" ),
        "filter_items_list" => __( "Filtrer la Liste des Reviews", "" ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( "Navigation dans la Liste des Reviews", "" ),
        "items_list" => __( "Liste des Reviews", "" ),
        "attributes" => __( "Attributs de la Review", "" ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( "Review Parente", "" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Reviews", "" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "description" => "",
        "public" => true,
        "publicly_queryable" => true,
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "has_archive" => false,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "exclude_from_search" => false,
        "capability_type" => "post",
        "map_meta_cap" => true,
        "hierarchical" => false,
        "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "%niche%", "with_front" => true ),
        "query_var" => false,
        "menu_icon" => "dashicons-awards",
        "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "custom-fields", "genesis-seo" ),
        "taxonomies" => array( "niche" ),
    );

    register_post_type( "review", $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts_review' );


function cptui_register_my_taxes_niche() {

    /**
     * Taxonomy: Niches.
     */

    $labels = array(
        "name" => __( "Niches", "" ),
        "singular_name" => __( "Niche", "" ),
        "menu_name" => __( "Niches", "" ),
        "all_items" => __( "Toutes les niches", "" ),
        "edit_item" => __( "Modifier la niche", "" ),
        "view_item" => __( "Voir la niche", "" ),
        "update_item" => __( "Mettre à jour le nom de la niche", "" ),
        "add_new_item" => __( "Ajouter nouvelle niche", "" ),
        "new_item_name" => __( "Nom de la nouvelle niche", "" ),
        "parent_item" => __( "Niche parente", "" ),
        "parent_item_colon" => __( "Niche parente :", "" ),
        "search_items" => __( "Rechercher les niches", "" ),
        "popular_items" => __( "Niches Populaires", "" ),
        "separate_items_with_commas" => __( "Séparer les niches avec des virgules", "" ),
        "add_or_remove_items" => __( "Ajouter ou enlever des Niches", "" ),
        "choose_from_most_used" => __( "Choisir parmi les plus utilisées", "" ),
        "not_found" => __( "Pas trouvé !", "" ),
        "no_terms" => __( "Pas de niches", "" ),
        "items_list_navigation" => __( "Navigation par liste des niches", "" ),
        "items_list" => __( "Liste des niches", "" ),
    );

    $args = array(
        "label" => __( "Niches", "" ),
        "labels" => $labels,
        "public" => true,
        "hierarchical" => true,
        "label" => "Niches",
        "show_ui" => true,
        "show_in_menu" => true,
        "show_in_nav_menus" => true,
        "query_var" => true,
        "rewrite" => array( 'slug' => 'niche', 'with_front' => false, 'hierarchical' => false ),
        "show_admin_column" => false,
        "show_in_rest" => false,
        "rest_base" => "",
        "show_in_quick_edit" => true,
    );
    register_taxonomy( "niche", array( "review" ), $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_taxes_niche' );

function wpse_5308_post_type_link( $link, $post ) {

    if ( $post->post_type === 'review' ) {
        if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'niche' ) )
            $link = str_replace( '%niche%', current( $terms )->slug, $link );
    }

    return $link;
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpse_5308_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one has tripped me up in the past. If you have a collision between a taxonomy and post type rewrite, it's important that you register the taxonomy *before* the post type.

Assuming you'd be ok with reworking your reviews URLs to the format /reviews/%niche%/%postname%, you'd need to change your post type as follows:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'reviews/%niche%', 'with_front' => false ),
'has_archive' => 'reviews',
```

your taxonomy:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'reviews', 'with_front' => false ),
```

and as mentioned above, do your call to `register_taxonomy()` before your call to `register_post_type()`. Visit Settings > Permalinks and resave to flush your rewrite rules.

Comment: Thank you Chris. It seems that I have a collision not between my "niche" taxonomy and "review" post type, but between one of these and my regular pages/posts.

For instance, the Rewrite Analyser for something like mysite.com/faq (which I would like to point to the existing FAQ page) returns "niche: faq". Actual URL returns a 404 page. I understand that my site interprets it as an item from the "niche" taxonomy, but being the newbie I am, I don't know why and how to change this.

Comment: You may have to rework your desired url structure to something like:

`mysite.com/reviews/coffee-maker/`  
`mysite.com/reviews/coffee-maker/keurig-k425`

Would that be acceptable?

Comment: (using this : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16902/permalink-rewrite-404-conflict-wordpress-taxonomies-cpt/16929#16929) I am now displaying pages! Need to find the same code for posts and that should do it.

Being a newbie, I wonder if these solutions are futureproof in terms of site loadtime and potential 404 problems...

Comment: Chris, I would be open to such a structure if there was no way around it to make a "futureproof" code. Can I ask how you would go about doing this?

Comment: I'll edit the info into my answer above, as comments are awful for posting code.